# IOC container trying to reference DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm writing a program at the moment that utilizes StructureMap as an IOC container.
I've implemented a couple of interfaces - `IUnitOfWork` and `IDataAccessRepository` that are resolved at run time with the the following classes (which are in their own project - `CardGame.EntityFrameworkProvider`).

**EntityFrameworkRepository.cs**

```
public class EntityFrameworkRepository<T> : IDataAccessRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    private DbContext _ctx;
    private DbSet<T> set;

    internal EntityFrameworkRepository(DbContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        set = _ctx.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Elements
    {
        get { return set; }
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return set.Find(id);
    }

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        set.Add(t);
    }

    public void Update(T t)
    {
         set.Attach(t);
        _ctx.Entry<T>(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(T t)
    {
        if (_ctx.Entry<T>(t).State == EntityState.Detached)
            set.Attach(t);
        set.Remove(t);
    }
}
```

**EntityFrameworkUnitofWork.cs**

```
public class EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionStringOrName"></param> 
    public EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork(string connectionStringOrName) : base(connectionStringOrName)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>());

        Creatures = new EntityFrameworkRepository<Models.Cards.Creature>(this);
        MagicCards = new EntityFrameworkRepository<Models.Cards.Magic>(this);
        EffectDescriptors = new EntityFrameworkRepository<Models.Effects.EffectDescriptor>(this);
    }


    #region Repositories
    public IDataAccessRepository<Models.Cards.Creature> Creatures
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IDataAccessRepository<Models.Cards.Magic> MagicCards
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IDataAccessRepository<Models.Effects.EffectDescriptor> EffectDescriptors
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    #endregion

    public new void SaveChanges()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Finally, in my main method - in another project - I bind the dependencies together using StructureMap.
**Main**

```
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.LookForRegistries();
                scan.Assembly("CardGame.DataAccess");
                scan.Assembly("CardGame.EntityFrameworkProvider");
            });

            #region Persistence
            x.For<CardGame.DataAccess.IUnitOfWork>().Use(new CardGame.EntityFrameworkProvider.EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork("MyConnectionString"));
            #endregion
        });
```

My issue is, is that with the `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` extending `DbContext`, my `CardGame.Server` (project containing Main.cs) is unable to compile because it doesn't (intentionally) contain a reference to EntityFramework. I'm trying to make this as database-agnostic as possible, and so far it has gone well, but the moment I made `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` extend `DbContext` (so I could apply a `DropCreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer), the whole thing went bang.

The reason I am making `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` extend `DbContext` is mainly because `IUnitOfWork` contains all the repositories that `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` (or other providers) need to implement. I initially didn't do this, but I reasoned that I am removing DAL from the models, rather than models from the DAL - and it would be so much easier to have properties on the `IUnitOfWork` object to grab the repositories I needed.

Have you any recommendations?

Adding a reference to EntityFramework *does fix the problem*, but that also means I have to add a reference to EntityFramework to my main project when it doesn't use it at all!

EDIT: Update! I managed to get it working, but ONLY by adding an EntityFramework reference to my project. I created a new class called `EntityFrameworkContext` with `DbSet<T>` in them, and that is created when an `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` is created (which has an initializer in it's static constructor). I guess this question boils down to:

Assume project with EF layer is Project A.
Project having layer injected into it is Project B.

How can I have EntityFramework settings on Project A (presumably in it's App.config) so that Project B doesn't need a reference to EntityFramework in it's configuration?
The whole idea is that the layer should be swappable with some other project (let's say NHibernate or ActiveRecord), and I shouldn't need to modify my main project to occupy those modifications. Furthermore, project A does not directly reference EntityFramework at  all - it makes no sense for it to have a reference to it.

Comment: I haven't used structuremap.  However, if the respositories are in DAL.DLL and not MainProject.DLL then MainProject.DLL will have no need for EntityFramework.DLL.  Perhaps you simply need to move the repositories to their own assembly.

Comment: See that's what I thought, @P.Brian.Mackey. There are 3 projects. DAL (contains interfaces), EntityFrameworkProvider (contains Entity framework relevant stuff and the implementation of the DAL) and Main (IOC resolver, main method, etc). Main complains about not having a reference to EntityFramework.dll, even when EF is never referenced from Main.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some DTO's.  I bet you are returning some entities from the DAL to the upper layer (Main).  Abstract those away by returning a custom class (DTO).  Like a property bag the "business layer" type instead of the DAL layer type.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey if you would like to look at the code you are more than welcome to yourself :) https://github.com/DanPantry/card-game. You will find Models inside CardGame.Models, DAL inside CardGame.DataAccess, the EntityFrameworkProvider inside CardGame.EntityFrameworkProvider and Main inside CardGame.Server. You might need to wait a bit as I am currently pushing.

Comment: There's no code at that link

Comment: Yes, my push is taking a lot longer than usual. Apparently the best 'net my internet can afford right now is 30KB/s upload. Combine that with NuGet package restore and you get a slow push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is this line

```
x.For<CardGame.DataAccess.IUnitOfWork>().Use(new CardGame.EntityFrameworkProvider.EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork("MyConnectionString"));
```

then you should probably think about using a [registry](http://docs.structuremap.net/RegistryDSL.htm). This way you can have a registry in your project referencing EntityFramework that looks something like this:

```
public class MyProjectRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyProjectRegistry()
    {
        For<CardGame.DataAccess.IUnitOfWork>().Use(new CardGame.EntityFrameworkProvider.EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork("MyConnectionString"));
    }
}
```

Since your ObjectFactory is already configured to look for registries, this should be enough to get it working.

Comment: I'll give this a go, one moment. Only issue I forsee that this means the provider has to "know" about StructureMap. It also means that the connection string name has to be stored inside of the EntityFrameworkProvider project (unless there is a different way? Configuration is not my forté)

Comment: You are correct, the provider needs a reference to StructureMap. This also means that you have self-configurable assemblies that you can reuse across projects, if you have this need. If you build everything through constructor injection though it should be your only use of StructureMap in the assembly.

Comment: Yup. I just set it up and it works like a dream. Now I need to work out how to pass a connection string to the registry in EntityFrameworkProvider, but that's configuration and a different question altogether. Thank you for your help!